# How to run/execute a gradle task?

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

How to run this gradle task/include it in build task (https://github.com/prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm)

```
task regressionSuite(type: Test, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    systemProperty('name', 'value')

    include '**/RegressionTestSuite.class'

    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

When I do `gradle clean regressionSuite` is always giving me build successful.. but it's not executing the specified class. Specific file is in the path.

I'm new to gradle.. any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure also the `testClassesDir` and the `classpath` property of the test task, otherwise the class you define in your pattern can't be found nor the test can be executed:

```
task regressionSuite(type: Test) {
    systemProperty('name', 'value')

    include '**/RegressionTestSuite.class'

    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
}
```